# autocomplete display relevant data in autocomplete window

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete, autocompletetextview

I have 3 input fields , 1 for data type and other 2 are its relevant.
when i press button in data type field i want to display autocomplete window like this [image: desired]

instead of this

[image: undesired]

And after select it should look like this

[image: result]

HTML

```
<tr>
   <td><input type="text" id="no_1" class="form-control"></td>            
   <td><input type="text" data-type="vehicle" id="vehicle_1" class="type form-control"></td>
   <td><input type="text" id="type_1" class="form-control"></td>
</tr>
```

JS

```
$(document).on('focus','.type',function(){
type = $(this).data('type');
if(type =='vehicle' )autoTypeNo = 1;   
$(this).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'autocomplete.php',
            dataType: "json",
            method: 'post',
            data: {
               name_startsWith: request.term,
               type: type
            },
             success: function( data ) {
                 response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                    var code = item.split("|");
                    return {
                        label: code[autoTypeNo],
                        value: code[autoTypeNo],
                        data : item
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    autoFocus: true,           
    minLength: 0,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        var names = ui.item.data.split("|");                       
        id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
        id = id_arr.split("_");
        $('#no_'+id[1]).val(names[0]);
        $('#vehicle_'+id[1]).val(names[1]);
        $('#type_'+id[1]).val(names[2]);
    }              
 });
});
```

Comment: Can you make an actual response from ajax be available? It is hard to work not being provided with all resourses

Comment: i have provided the actual response in above images

Comment: my script works and gives result as like image 2 above i need some changes in it to get result as image 1 above.

Comment: Ok, but what your result looks like? Can you post it?

Comment: like image 3 but it displays data in autocomplete window like image 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to alter autocomplete.php then to return all 3 values, you can do this in a json array easily http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php then read the values in your jquery script.

This is your updated JS script

```
$(document).on('focus','.type',function(){
type = $(this).data('type');
if(type =='vehicle' )autoTypeNo = 1;   
$(this).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'autocomplete.php',
            dataType: "json",
            method: 'post',
            data: {
               name_startsWith: request.term,
              type: type
            },
             success: function( data ) {
                 response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                    //var code = item.split("|");
                    return {
                        label: item.no + '-' + item.vehicle + '-' + item.type,
                        value: item.vehicle,
                        data : item
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    autoFocus: true,           
    minLength: 0,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        //var names = ui.item.data.split("|");                       
        id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
        id = id_arr.split("_");
        $('#no_'+id[1]).val(ui.item.data.no);
        $('#vehicle_'+id[1]).val(ui.item.data.vehicle);
        $('#type_'+id[1]).val(ui.item.data.type);
    }              
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had issues with presentation.
The out put look like this :
[image: selected]
Is it something like that you want ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <style>

  </style>
<body>

<h1>The onclick Event</h1>

<p>The onclick event is used to trigger a function when an element is clicked on.</p>
<table>
<tr>
   <td>no:</td>            
   <td><label for="search">vehicle: </label></td>
   <td>type:</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input type="text" id="no_1" class="form-control"></td>            
   <td><input type="text" data-type="vehicle" id="search" class="type form-control"></td>
   <td><input type="text" id="type_1" class="form-control"></td>
</tr>
</table>




<script>
$(document).on('focus','.type',function(){
 type = $(this).data('type');
 if(type =='vehicle' )autoTypeNo = 1;   
 //$(this).autocomplete({
 $.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
     _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
    var that = this;
    $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
     //here you modify the presentation of the label
     item.label=item.no + " - " + item.label + " - " + item.category;
     that._renderItemData( ul, item );
    });
     }
   });

  var data = [
    { no:"GL-446", label: "truck", category: "4 wheel" },
    { no:"GL-446",label: "andreastr", category: "4 wheel" },
    { no:"GL-446",label: "antaltr", category: "4 wheel" },
    { no:"GL-446",label: "annhhx10tr", category: "Products" },
    { no:"GL-446",label: "annk K12tr", category: "Products" },
    { no:"2A corsica",label: "annttop C13tr", category: "Products" },
    { no:"GL-446",label: "anders anderssontr", category: "People" },
    { no:"GL-446",label: "andreas anderssontr", category: "People" },
    { no:"GL-446",label: "andreas johnsontr", category: "People" }
  ];
  
 $( "#search" ).catcomplete({
    delay: 0,
    source: /*function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
     url : 'autocomplete.php',
     dataType: "json",
     method: 'post',
     data: {
        name_startsWith: request.term,
        type: type
     },
      success: function( data ) {
       response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
       var code = item.split("|");
       return {
        label: trunk,
        value: 10,
        data : 2
       }
      }));
     }
    });
   },*/
   data,
   //autoFocus: true,           
   minLength: 0,
   select: function(event, ui) {
    /*var names = ui.item.data.split("|");                       
    id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
    id = id_arr.split("_");
    $('#no_'+id[1]).val(names[0]);
    $('#vehicle_'+id[1]).val(names[1]);
    $('#type_'+id[1]).val(names[2]);*/
    if(ui.item) { 
     $( "#no_1" ).attr('value',ui.item.no);
     $( "#type_1" ).attr('value',ui.item.category);
    }
   }
    });

});



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: after select it should look like image 3

Comment: Sorry, i modified to add the no and the type at the selection.

Comment: Is this not possible with my script with a little change.Because it's working but the desired thing is to display these three input combine in label as mentioned in image 1. my script working with image 2 and 3. i want image 1 condition instead of image 2.

Comment: Could you try to take back the source with your data to see if it work with it. I comment your code in the code above. I allways have presentation issues, but i think it look like what you want (exept the trashy presentation).

Comment: thanks for your answer it is working except an extra li bellow the table.but the problem is your way of coding is a bit different. And it is difficult to understand that's why   i want it in y own code to edit.

Comment: can you make it workable as @Harshali Talele's  answer just make changes to label in success response.

Comment: After a lot of research, i found out where to modify the presentation like you said. I think we can't do shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Inside success function, you need to form labels like 'GL446 - truck - 4 wheel' and value as 'truck' as per below example -

http://jsfiddle.net/43aeh78L/2/

Probably your success method would look like this-

```
success: function( data ) {
     response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
         var code = item.split("|");
             return {
                 label: code[0] + "-" + code[1] + "-" + code[2],
                 value: code[autoTypeNo],
                 data : item
             }
         }));
     }
```

**Edit**:
I guess `item` object inside response function contains all the 3 values, then you can just append them to form a label String as - `code[0] + "-" + code[1] + "-" + code[2]`

Comment: how to join these 3 input field in label according to my script ?

Comment: What does your 'item' object look like inside response function?

Comment: i have changed this, but the result is same as image 2.

Comment: objects are as mentioned in above scrip no,vehicle,type.